# How can I unit test Perl functions that print to the screen?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to use [Test::More](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Test::More) to unit test Perl functions that print to the screen.

I understand that this output may interfere with tools such as [prove](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/prove).

How can I capture this output so I can print it with `diag()`, and also run tests on the output itself?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**UPDATE:** IMHO, the correct answer to this question ought to be to use [Test::Output](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Test::Output):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Test::More tests => 1;
use Test::Output;

sub myfunc { print "This is a test\n" }

stdout_is(\&myfunc, "This is a test\n", 'myfunc() returns test output');
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> tm
1..1
ok 1 - myfunc() returns test output
```

*I am leaving the original answer for reference as, I believe, it still illustrates a useful technique*.

You can localize `STDOUT` and reopen to a scalar before calling the function, restore afterward:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Test::More tests => 1;

sub myfunc { print "This is a test\n" }

sub invoke {
    my $sub = shift;
    my $stdout;
    {
        local *STDOUT;
        open STDOUT, '>', \$stdout
            or die "Cannot open STDOUT to a scalar: $!";
        $sub->(@_);
        close STDOUT
            or die "Cannot close redirected STDOUT: $!";
    }
    return $stdout;
}

chomp(my $ret =  invoke(\&myfunc));

ok($ret eq "This is a test", "myfunc() prints test string" );
diag("myfunc() printed '$ret'");
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> tm
1..1
ok 1 - myfunc() prints test string
# myfunc() printed 'This is a test'
```

For versions of `perl` older than 5.8, you probably need to use [IO::Scalar](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO::Scalar), but I do not know much about how things worked before 5.8.

Comment: Just when I think I'm wasting too much time on SO, I learn something cool! Thanks.

Comment: Well, technically they don't, but it sure is nice when they do. :p (+1, that's an awesome module)

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I think the orginal answer does too much work to get the job done. It's too complicated. I'm a bit biased toward Test::Output though, but I use it as a last resort.

Comment: +1 for usefulness. Very few of my numerous libraries ever printed anything worth testing on the output so I never encountered this one before.

Comment: I wasnt going to comment but... There is a book "Intermediate Perl" that has a chapter "Introduction to Testing" and one of the exercises tells you to test a certain package's subroutine's output with 'is' and leaves you hanging, it took a while to figure out this is what I was supposed to do. Perhaps the author expected us (since we were "Intermediate" at the time) to know to use Test::Output, but I have no idea how we were supposed to know, i mean, im not a clairvoyant as far as i know... but thanks anyways this got me out of a two day rut.

Comment: Nice answer.. but it partly solved my problem.. @Sinan Ünür if you would be so kind, how can I unit test a function with a parameter that prints on a screen? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363427/unit-test-a-perl-function-with-parameters-that-print-to-a-screen

Answer (score 7):

I'd look at letting a module handle this for you. Look at [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Capture::Tiny).

Answer (score 7):

If this is code that you are writing yourself, change it so that the print statements don't use a default filehandle. Instead, give yourself a way to set the output filehandle to anything you like:

```
sub my_print {
     my $self = shift;
     my $fh = $self->_get_output_fh;
     print { $fh } @_;
     }

sub _get_output_fh { $_[0]->{_output}  || \*STDOUT }
sub _set_output_fh { $_[0]->{_output} = $_[1] } # add validation yourself
```

When you test, you can call `_set_output_fh` to give it your testing filehandle (perhaps even an [IO::Null](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IO-Null) handle). When another person wants to use your code but capture the output, they don't have to bend over backward to do it because they can supply their own filehandle.

When you find a part of your code that is hard to test or that you have to jump through hoops to work with, you probably have a bad design. I'm still amazed at how testing code makes these things apparent, because I often wouldn't think about them. If it's hard to test, make it easy to test. You generally win if you do that.

Comment: Amen. Writing unit tests (or planning for them if you do TDD, whether you know it or not) very often results in marked design improvements.