# Test fails under prove if it writes to stdout without newline

Tags: perl, testing, perl-prove

When I run a perl test using the `prove` utility, it fails if the method under test contains `print` statements that are not terminated by newlines.

```
use Test::More tests=>1;

ok(foo(), "calling foo");

sub foo{
    print "A";
    1;
}
```

This results in

```
Bad plan.  You planned 1 tests but ran 0.
```

If I append a newline: `print "A\n";` the test passes.

(Note that if I simply execute the test `perl mytest.t` rather than using `prove` it passes either way).

Any ideas why this might be, and how to work around it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1538260/1030675
The output of `print` interferes with what `prove` expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a quick workaround:

```
$|=0;     # no auto-flush
```

...but I have no idea (yet) why this works.

Comment: Thanks this works and is simpler than localising stdout etc.

I can see that when I do this, with the verbose switch enabled, that the test print statements appear on a line _after_ the `ok - test passed` line, whereas before they appeared on the same line.

It's almost as if `prove` were parsing its own output when deciding if the test run had passed 100%. (Note that the original test was not failing per se; rather `prove` was discounting it when tallying up the number of tests run.)