# Unit test a Perl function with parameters that print to a screen

Tags: perl, unit-testing

How can I unit test a perl function with a parameter that prints to a screen?

```
sub test {
  my $var = shift;
  if( $var eq "hello") {
    print "Hello";
  }
  else {
    print "World";
  }
}
```

I want to fully cover all the conditions in a function that prints to a screen but I don't know how..

I saw this answer at stackoverflow [How can I unit test Perl functions that print to the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538260/how-can-i-unit-test-perl-functions-that-print-to-the-screen)

Yes the answer can unit test a function that outputs a string but only if there are no parameters in the function required.. in my case I can use this:

```
stdout_is(\&test, "World", 'test() return World');
```

but how can I test `print "Hello";`?

**EDIT**

I tried using this test cases:

```
should_print_hello();
should_print_world();


sub should_print_world
{
  stdout_is(\&test, "World", "should_print_world");
}

sub should_print_hello
{
  # this does not work and outputs error
  stdout_is(\&test("hello"), "Hello", "should_print_hello");
}
```

since `stdout_is`' parameter for the function is only a code reference to a function (if I'm not mistaken), it doesn't have the `function(variables_here)`.

I've also read the [perl Test::Output manual](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Output/lib/Test/Output.pm) but I still can't find a solution.. Are there any other ways or did I missed something?

so my main question is:
**How can I unit test a perl function(with arguments) that only prints to a screen(stdout)?**

Comment: @SinanÜnür I am trying to make unit tests to legacy codes and there are instances that the subroutines does not follow single responsibility principle... and my question here is "how can i unit test a perl subroutine that has a parameter in it when it only prints stdout"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to wrap the call you want to test in an anonymous subroutine

I am using `output_is` to test both `stdout` and `stderr`. The fourth test here should fail if you have `use warnings` in place as you should

```
output_is(sub { test('hello') }, 'Hello', '', 'Test specific output');
output_is(sub { test('xxx') },   'World', '', 'Test non-specific output');
output_is(sub { test('') },      'World', '', 'Test null string parameter output');
output_is(sub { test() },        'World', '', 'Test no-parameter output');
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for! so `\&func` is just the same as `sub {...}`

Comment: @catzilla: You could write different functions and pass references to them, yes. `sub { ... }` is just a way of defining a subroutine and getting a reference to it without giving it a name

Answer (score 3):

Your edit clarified the question by pointing out the fact that you didn't know about [anonymous subroutines](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsub):

> To define an anonymous subroutine at runtime:
>
> ```
> $subref = sub BLOCK;                 # no proto
> $subref = sub (PROTO) BLOCK;         # with proto
> $subref = sub SIG BLOCK;             # with signature
> $subref = sub : ATTRS BLOCK;         # with attributes
> $subref = sub (PROTO) : ATTRS BLOCK; # with proto and attributes
> $subref = sub : ATTRS SIG BLOCK;     # with attribs and signature
> ```

When you write `\&test("hello")`, `perl` calls `test` with the argument `"hello"` and tries to take a reference to its return value.

When you write `\&test`, `perl` gives you a reference to the subroutine `test`. For example, if you have `my $f = \&test`, you can later use `$f->()` to invoke `test`.

But, in case you want to defer calling `test` with an argument, that would not help as `my $f = \&test("hello")` will immediately call `test` with the argument `"hello"` and store a reference to its return value in `$f`. This is natural as following the name of a subroutine with an argument list causes its invocation.

Except, you can wrap a specific call to `test` in an anonymous subroutine. If you have `my $f = sub { test("hello") }`, what you have in `$f` is a function which, when invoked, calls `test` with the argument `"hello"` and returns its return value.

You use this to define [closures](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlref#Function-Templates) which will help you reduce repetition in your tests:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;
use Test::Output;

sub hello {
    print +($_[0] eq 'hello') ? 'Hello' : 'World';
}

sub bye {
    print +($_[0] eq 'bye') ? 'Bye' : 'World';
}

my @hello_tests = (
    [ [ 'hello' ] => 'Hello' => '' ],
    [ [ 'xxx' ]   => 'World' => '' ],
    [ [ ' ' ]     => 'World' => '' ],
    [ [ ]         => 'World' => '' ],
);

my @bye_tests = (
    [ [ 'bye' ]   => 'Bye'   => '' ],
    [ [ 'xxx' ]   => 'World' => '' ],
    [ [ ' ' ]     => 'World' => '' ],
    [ [ ]         => 'World' => '' ],
);

sub make_tester {
    my $f = shift;
    sub {
        my $args = shift;
        my $out = shift;
        my $err = shift;
        output_is(
            sub { $f->(@$args) },
            $out,
            $err,
            sprintf(
                "called with (%s) prints '%s' on stdout, and '%s' on stderr",
                join(',', @$args),
                $out ? $out : '*nothing*',
                $err ? $err : '*nothing*',
            )
        );
    };
}

my @test_list = (
    [ \&hello, \@hello_tests ],
    [ \&bye,   \@bye_tests ],
);

for my $atest (@test_list) {
    my $tester = make_tester($atest->[0]);
    $tester->(@$_) for @{ $atest->[1] };
}
```

Of course, it is possible to make this more compact, by not explicitly declaring `@hello_tests` and `@bye_tests`, and stuffing everything into `@test_list`, but I thought this made the exposition clearer.

Call make tester to generate an anonymous subroutine, which, when invoked with an argument list, expected standard output, expected standard error, and test description, tests the output of the function that was passed as its sole argument.

Then, go through the list of tests, creating an anonymous sub that invokes the function generated above for each test case.